# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: data and salt arguments required

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I have this error with this code :

```
async function get(user) {
  user = await Joi.validate(user, userSchemaGet, { abortEarly: false });
  await User.findOne(
    {_id: user._id}, 
    (err, res) => {
      if(err){
        console.log("ERROR : ")
        console.log(err)
      } else {
        console.log("res")
        console.log(res);
        if(bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10) === res.hashedPassword) {
          return res;
        }
      }
    });
}
```

I read all the stackoverflow on this subject but nothing happens. 
ps : it's working perfectly last day ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Probably `user.password` is null or undefined. Check the `user` value before you pass it to the `hash` function.

2) `bcrypt.hash` is a promise, but you are using it as a normal function.

3) `bcrypt` has a special compare function that is meant to check if the passowrd matches the hash. You should use it here.

[Bcrypt docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt)